Does "people who own cars" mean "people who own cars in general" (so 1+ cars) or "people who own 2+ cars"?
I want to talk about people who own at least one car, and the phrase people who own cars (in general) springs to my mind as it's shorter. However, since cars is plural there, the phrase also means people who have more than one car.
So, can the phrase mean both or does it only mean the latter?

In conversational contexts, "people who own cars" is synonymous with "car-owners" but if there's any chance that in the course of your text you would be distinguishing between people who own one-car  and people who own more than one car,  you could avoid "people who own cars" by using "car-owners" instead, when referring to anyone who owns at least one car.  Of course, you could run into the issue of owning versus leasing :-)

A fun case to think about—but probably best to avoid using—is "a person who owns cars", where "a person" is a singular noun, but otherwise the situation is similar to the answers here.

Badly worded though.

@TimR in the UK we have the concept of "registered keeper" which isn't the same as legal ownership in the case of leasing.  But in general possession is more likely to be what we care about than legal title

People who own one or more cars.


People who own cars...

This refers to anybody who owns at least one car.
If you only wanted to refer to people who own more than one car, you should clarify that. For example:

People who own more than one car...
People who own multiple cars...


Even though "people who own cars" is most plausibly intended to mean "people who own at least one car", technically this isn't definitive.

What about me? I own two thirds of a car.

That's a different issue entirely. Many people who "own a car" don't really own it at all. The bank owns it, and they are gradually buying it from the bank each month. The same goes with home ownership. We would say that someone owns a home, even though the bank owns it. Or perhaps they own it with a spouse, so they really only own 50%. We would still say they own a home.

@ryang So what's your point? What is the purpose of this forum? Is it to negate the most plausible answer because of an obscure use case that contradicts it? I would imagine you could create some context for just about any answer on here where the answer doesn't hold true.  I doubt that would be very helpful to someone learning English.

Ambiguity exists on a spectrum, and in this case the alternative interpretation isn't all that contrived or far-fetched or outre, merely implausible. Let's move on.

@swmcdonnell The bank does not own the car or the home.  The own a debt with the car or the home as the security, and can take ownership if the debt is not repaid.

@swmcdonnell Stackexchange is not a forum, it is a Q&A, and OP has asked a question, you answered.  The comments are supposed to help clarify and improve both.  If someone wants a chat we have [chat] dedicated to that.

If a couple owns one car between them, both people would normally be described as car-owners (or "people who own cars").  So counting N people who own cars doesn't mean you'll count ≥ N cars among those people, which the answer implies. However English isn't maths (and co-ownership is a valid concept), so the answer is correct in practice

@gerrit - there are various models of car purchase, some of which use the car as security as you say, and some where the possessor merely leases the vehicle and doesn't get ownership until the end.  But that's a complete tangent from the question and answer, as most of those people will answer "yes" when asked, "Is this your car, sir?" (or "madam")

@TobySpeight Well, yes, and when you invite someone to your rented home, calling it "your apartment" is also normal.

@gerrit my god, my boss, my country, my wife, my child, my dog, my pen, my mortgage - "my" in all cases - or "your", of course -  but some very different senses (there's a classic list but I can't remember it or be bothered to track it down).  "Owner" is slightly more restrictive, but the difference between owned, but with a loan secured against it and leased is almost certainly immaterial for our purposes

This answer was flagged in another SE that I use. When I read the answer, I thought, "What... this is a good answer; nothing controversial here." But then, as I read through the comments that followed, I thought, "Wow... a lot of whiners and nit-pickers here; glad I don't use this SE." +1 for a solid, reasonable and correct answer.

OP's query:

Does "people who own cars" mean "people who own cars in general" (so 1+ cars) or "people who own 2+ cars"?
However, since cars is plural there, the phrase also means people who have more than one car.

Let's consider the two sentences:

People who own cars.
People who own a car.

In everyday speech, both the sentences include single and multiple car owners. (1 and 1+ car owners)
However,

People who own one car..
is ambiguous. It may mean only one or more than one.
So you have to specify.
People who own only one car..
(Exclusive - no more, no less).
People who own one or more cars..
(Inclusive - may own more than one car).
People who own at least one car.
(All car owners - single car or multiple cars).
People who own at least two cars.
(Multiple car owners only, single car owners are excluded)


I agree that (1) is (technically) ambiguous, however I feel that (2) "own a car" is most reasonably understood as "own at least one car", whereas (3) "own one car" is most reasonably understood as "own exactly one car."

@ryang It's a Mitch Hedberg ambiguity (“I used to do drugs. I still do, but I used to, too.”). Given that there are more common ways of stating the "alternative" interpretation (e.g. (2)), native speakers usually assume that if you meant it the other way you would have said it differently, leaving the plain reading of the sentence clear through process of elimination, despite the technical ambiguity.

@R.M. Haha, that quotation made me chuckle. Yes, I indicated the same in my comment under the other answer.

3 is mistaken. "People who own one car..
is ambiguous. It may mean only one or more than one." = Mistake buzzer

@Lambie Try putting this in front of some school kids. I am sure they would need a clarification what is meant "only one" or "at least one"

How you can say that "people who own one car" is ambiguous is completely beyond me.

@Lambie So you think, "People who own two cars" means only people who own two cars (no more, no less). What is the problem being clear ? What is the use of "only"?

Peopl;e who own two cars means that EACH of the persons in the group of eople own two cars. Boys who read one book will not get very far. ONE = ONE

@Lambie It’s similar to the old gag, “Which month has 28 days?” – the correct answer being either ‘February’ (has exactly 28 days) or ‘all of them’ (there are no months that do not have 28 days, though all except one also have 29 and 30, and seven also have 31). It’s impossible to own two cars without simultaneously owning one car. So yes, 3 is technically ambiguous, even if (as R.M. says) it’s almost certain to mean the same as 4 in actual use.

@JanusBahsJacquet Isn't it interesting how how many days does May have? 28 feels more patently wrong than May has 28 days? This is another illustration of my point, made under swmcdonnell's answer, that ambiguity exists on a spectrum. Anyhow, my first comment above does point out that "owning one car" and "owning a car" are commonly interpreted differently.

@JanusBahsJacquet The same explanation I thought. Thank you. The point is there is a possibility of misinterpretation.

You bait and switch. I said that what you said about one car is not true: "People who own one car..
is ambiguous. It may mean only one or more than one." And I stand by it.

@Lambie Someone has understood why it is ambiguous (not clear) or can be misinterpreted and has explained it with an example of month - (Which month has 28 days?)

No, it is not similar. I own one house. I own one car. No ambiguity and no similarity to any gag. "People who own one car..
is ambiguous. It may mean only one or more than one." is not ambiguous.

Can you use "car owners" instead?

Talking about mobility, the highest share of car owners in selected countries worldwide can be found in Malaysia, where 95 percent of consumers are part of this category. The second highest ranking country is Italy with 95 percent of respondents falling into this category. The last place is taken by Philippines.

SOURCE: Statista
Share of car owners in 56 countries & territories worldwide, as of February 2024

I actually retain this answer to be the solution to the OP's dilemma.

The OP is looking for a short unambiguous phrase, well car owners is shorter than “people who own cars", and doesn't exclude the fact that owners can be people own only one vehicle.

In addition it would also open up to distinguishing "single-car owners" and "multiple car owners."

While some other answers suggest one person owns multiple cars, which may a scenario which actually reflects economic reality in some cases, that doesn't have to be the case.  (It could be true.  It might not.)
This structure of sentence does suggest at least two cars.  However, it doesn't necessarily mean two cars per person.
Alice and Bob bought a car together.  Carol and Dan bought a car together.  Each one of these people pitched in a portion of the car, and is a partial owner, meaning they are both owners (and each owns a portion of the car's value).
Alice and Bob and Carol and Dan are the people who own these two cars.  If someone looks at bicycles and cars and asks, "Who are the people who own cars in this parking lot", they are people who own cars.
If, in addition to the above description, Frank owns two cars, then you have Alice and Bob and Caro and Dan and Frank are the people who own cars.
Let's just show another example using the same sort of sentence design/structure: If you go to an outdoor park with basketball hoops, you may find there are multiple basketballs being used.  There may be multiple people who own basketballs.  The sentence structure does imply multiple people, and multiple basketballs, but not that each basketball owner is a person who individually owns multiple basketballs.  It could be true.  It might not.

By far the most common way of owning multiple cars is the multi-car family where a husband, a wife and maybe a teenage child each have a car 'of their own' but the finances, insurance and suchlike are intermingled.
This is by far the most common way for a person to have several cars in their driveway, so much so you should probably clarify if this is what you mean or not :)
The likes of Jay Leno, where one person owns 180 cars would be called car collectors. A person who owns one practical car for day-to-day driving, and a second less practical vehicle such as a classic car or a kit car would be called car enthusiasts but that also encompasses people with a single car they really like.
I'm not aware of any succinct term that covers all people with more than one car, without also including multi-car families.

Well sure, if one member of the family has multiple cars, then the family does too.

This answer is far detached from the question.
